# Equalizing the lengths of all the lists within a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, compilation, esoteric-languages

**Important context:** [Dig on the esolang wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dig)

I am making an compiler for a esoteric programming language, using a 2d list to account for the language’s 2d nature. The problem comes when I need all the lists in the one mega list to be of same length.

This:
`[[“#”,”#”],[“#”,”#”,”#”]]`

Needs be this:
`[[“#”,”#”,” “],[“#”,”#”,”#”]]`

Thanks!

Comment: you are just appending to the end?

Comment: of each sublist?

Comment: Yes, if that’s what you need, it is a yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> mega_list = [["#","#"],["#","#","#"]]
>>> for a in mega_list:
...     a.extend([" "] * (max(map(len, mega_list)) - len(a)))
...
>>> mega_list
[['#', '#', ' '], ['#', '#', '#']]
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply fillvalues to uneven lists, use the itertools.zip_longest function.

```
import itertools as it

lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
lists = list(zip(*it.zip_longest(*lists,fillvalue=' ')))
print(lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, finding the max length of the lists first:

```
max_length = max( len(i) for i in l)
[ i + [" "]*(max_length-len(i)) for i in l ]
```